# How to move data in desired format in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var array = [-3,0,0, 1,55,56,232]
```

### Desired output

```
array = [56,-3,0,0,1,232,55]
```

I am facing difficulty in getting desired output. I know this is some easy question but I have tried and not successful. Please help

### I have tried like this:--

```
  array.unshift(array.splice(5, 1)[0]);
  array.unshift(array.splice(4, 1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuold use `push` instead of `unshift` second time as you want to move `55` to the end of the array. Also after you do `splice` and `unshift` the first time, the index of `55` becomes `5`, because you move `56` to the begining.

```js
let array = [-3, 0, 0, 1, 55, 56, 232];
array.unshift(array.splice(5, 1)[0]);
array.push(array.splice(5, 1)[0]);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this (taking advantage of ES6):

```
array = [array[5], ...array.slice(0,4), array[6], array[4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but here's one way of going about it. The `unshift()` line is the same, in which the sixth element is brought to the start. Next, the last element is grabbed and inserted into the fifth position. Finally, the new last element in the array is removed.

```js
let array = [-3, 0, 0, 1, 55, 56, 232]

array.unshift(array.splice(5, 1)[0]);
array.splice(array[array.length - 1], 0, array[array.length - 1]);
array.pop();

console.log(array);
```